# Img not showing in modal on mobile with Bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap (with Grunt) to built my portfolio.

I have the project images in different modals, all not showing up on mobile. I made them all .jpg & RGB, as another answer had told me. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the link (click on an image and click "Fullsize") on mobile:

http://qrioza.nl/portfolio/new/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was cache, after some time the problem was solved. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should really post some code and your testing conditions like browser to get the best help. But from what I can see this image (IJ-fullscreen.jpg) is not uploaded to your server, here is the current coded path: `img/projects/fullscreen/IJ-fullscreen.jpg` which is causing it to not display, because as far as your browser is concerned it doesn't exist. Also your last 2 profile projects have the same IJ-fullscreen.jpg image they are linking to in your "Fullsize" link, just FYI.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know it doesn't exist, but it is working already (probably cache). I am now figuring out why some of the images keep disappearing on mobile...